# DOCKER ASSIGN a shell value to ENV in DOCKERFILE

Tags: docker, shell, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm drastically looking for the solution of passing the value to the `ENV` variable in `DOCKERFILE`.

```
EX:

FROM alphine

COPY domainname.txt .

ENV NAME=$(cat /domainname.txt)
```

Comment: A Dockerfile is a recipe for building an image. It is not a program that is run when you run the image. ENV statements in your dockerfile sets a default value of the dockerfile. You can override the value when you run the image by specifying the `-e` option on the `docker run` command.

Comment: appreciate for rapid response .. i want my image to get wrapped with all the required env to start the db_container. where i dont want to pass the env via docker-compose or docker run..

Comment: Do you want them embedded in the image at build time or do you want to pass them from files (like domainname.txt) at run-time?

Comment: embedded is true..

Comment: Then what you've already done is fine. Can you explain what you think is wrong with it?

Comment: Could you please check the above code is your machine .. that isn't working and throwing the error saying that KEY=VALUE type allows kind off..

Answer (score 0):

If you insist to get `NAME` value when docker build, you could use next:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM alpine

ARG NAME
ENV NAME=${NAME}
```

**domainname.txt:**

```
hello
```

**Execution:**

```
$ docker build --build-arg NAME=$(cat ./domainname.txt) -t abc:1 . --no-cache
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine
 ---> d4ff818577bc
Step 2/3 : ARG NAME
 ---> Running in f1c58e816499
Removing intermediate container f1c58e816499
 ---> dc4d5894440b
Step 3/3 : ENV NAME=${NAME}
 ---> Running in 9b8f98a3857c
Removing intermediate container 9b8f98a3857c
 ---> 2b0c68ddc994
Successfully built 2b0c68ddc994
Successfully tagged abc:1
$ docker run --rm -it abc:1 env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=2155d7368c3e
TERM=xterm
NAME=hello
HOME=/root
```

You could see above `NAME` be assigned as `hello`.

Simple explanation:

1. `NAME=$(cat ./domainname.txt)` assign the `hello` to `NAME`
2. `--build-arg` pass the `hello` to docker build's `ARG NAME`
3. `ENV NAME=${NAME}` get the `hello` from `ARG NAME`

Comment: Sorry as i clearly mention i want that to be pre-built with all required env's